# Dynamic Creation of Table using Stored Procedure Without a Use of OpenRowSet in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

Q.--> An alternative of `OpenRowSet` in SQL Server

Description:

I have created a procedure which uses Dynamic `PIVOT` to get a result. I have a table which contains column DateRange with values Jan-2014 Feb-2014 Mar-2014 etc...

Using dynamic query in `PIVOT`, I am able to get the desired output by passing columns from  table. The `@Columns` variable is set by using `Stuff` function with `FOR XML Path`.
By passing this `@Columns` variable into dynamic sql query for `PIVOT` I am able to achieve the following:

Result table:

```
Col1   | Jan-2014  | Feb-2014 | ...............
-------------------------------------------------------
ABC    | 123       |11231     | ...............
ASDF   |123123     |123123    | ...............
```

---

Now I have to create a physical table which will be having a result from the above procedure as shown in the table. As I mentioned the procedure is containing dynamic query, it is having `EXECUTE`. Because of which I am not able to create a table inside the procedure.

I tried to create a view as well but that also didn't worked as my procedure contains variable declaration.

To achieve this I used `OpenRowSet` in a script that runs on a daily basis.

My problem is: I cannot use `OpenRowSet`, and I am not able to create a physical table from a stored procedure. The `OpenRowSet` contains connection string that is why I cannot use it.

Please suggest...

EDIT 1:

My procedure for creating dynamic `PIVOT` table:

```
DECLARE 
        @Columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(DateRange) 
                         FROM View
                         ORDER BY ',' + QUOTENAME(DateRange) 
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @Query = 'SELECT Col1, Col2, ' + @Columns + 
             ' FROM (SELECT Col1, Col2, [DateRange], Col3 FROM View) A
               PIVOT
                 (SUM(Col3) FOR DateRange IN (' + @Columns + ') ) S '

Execute (@Query)
```

and script for creating a physical table

```
SELECT * 
INTO Physicaltable 
FROM 
    OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'ConnectionString',
               'SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON;EXECUTE (AboveProcedure)')
```

Comment: Why do you believe you cannot create the table in the stored procedure? If you passed in a table name as another parameter you could include that in your dynamic query changing the SELECT to be a SELECT...INTO... I hope the real procedure doesn't just build a query from Columns like that though, at the very least I would have the procedure error out if Columns contained any single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use OPENROWSET, you could create a loopback linked server and use OPENQUERY or EXECUTE AT.

```
DECLARE @srv nvarchar(4000);
SET @srv = @@SERVERNAME; -- gather this server name

-- Create the linked server
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
@server     = N'LOOPBACK',
@srvproduct = N'SQLServ', -- it’s not a typo: it can’t be “SQLServer”
@provider   = N'SQLNCLI', -- change to SQLOLEDB for SQLServer 2000
@datasrc    = @srv;


-- Set the authentication to "current security context"
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
@rmtsrvname  = N'LOOPBACK',
@useself     = N'True',
@locallogin  = NULL,
@rmtuser     = NULL,
@rmtpassword = NULL;
```

[I blogged about it some years ago.](http://spaghettidba.com/2011/11/16/discovering-the-output-of-dbcc-commands/)

Another option is using some kind of CLR trickery to interpret the result set definition and create a target table based on the type and length of the columns.

If you're not allowed to use OPENROWSET, I highly doubt you will be allowed to use CLR, though. In this case, a third option could be using [sp_describe_first_result_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx) and code your table creation script in T-SQL. It requires SQL Server 2012 or newer.

Comment: Thanks spaghetti... Although I cannot use Openquery as well as it also includes sort of server information. And about sp_describe_first_result_set, we are having 2008 R2 so that is not possible as well

Comment: @RohitJain What about a CLR procedure?

Comment: Thanks bro! but I am able to solve the issue. A very silly solution: I added the creation of table in my dynamic sql query.

Comment: @RohitJain and @spaghettidba: regarding `sp_describe_first_result_set` and not being on SQL Server 2012, there is an equivalent proc in my SQL# library ( http://www.SQLsharp.com/ ) called `DB_DescribeResultSets`. Yes, it is SQLCLR, and yes, it is in the Full version only (i.e. not free), but it does run on SQL 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2 :).

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this :

```
SET @Query = 'SELECT Col1, Col2, ' + @Columns + ' INTO PhysicalTable
              FROM (SELECT Col1, Col2, [DateRange], Col3 FROM View) A
               PIVOT
                 (SUM(Col3) FOR DateRange IN (' + @Columns + ') ) S '

Execute (@Query)
```

And now I am able to remove the OpenRowSet.